# What's the recent released 750GeV particle's spin?

Tags: quantum-gravity, large-hadron-collider, beyond-the-standard-model

I was told that it has recently been confirmed to be spin-2 particle, and potentially to be graviton. I'm pretty interested in how this has been examined.

Edit: 
During the Moriond 2016 conference, CMS clearly stated it is a spin-2 rather than spin-0 particle (spin-1 has already been ruled out by Landau-Yang theorem [1-2]). For a review, see [3].

The yesterday report on ATLAS claims new analysis and new methods gave promising result, which is what I'm looking forward to know. Also I would like some experts to give an introduction to the physics picture how to examine the spin, and what's the theoretical model [4] means.

Edit2: on Aug 5th, ICHEP conference, the new result is gonna to be published.

Edit3: ICHEP conference released ATLAS & CMS results [5-6]. ATLAS doesn't contain newest spin-2 selection results (which could be something), while CMS gives disappointing results.

---

[1] C.-N. Yang, Selection Rules for the Dematerialization of a Particle Into Two Photons, Phys. Rev. 77 (1950) 242–245. http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.77.242;

[2] L. D. Landau, On the angular momentum of a system of two photons, Dokl. Akad. Nauk Ser. Fiz. 60 (2) (1948) 207–209. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-010586-4.50070-5.

[3] Strumia, Alessandro. "Interpreting the 750 GeV digamma excess: a review." arXiv preprint [arXiv:1605.09401](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09401) (2016).

[4] Dillon, Barry M., and Veronica Sanz. "A little KK graviton at 750 GeV." arXiv preprint [arXiv:1603.09550](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09550) (2016).

[5] http://indico.cern.ch/event/432527/contributions/1072336/attachments/1321033/1981068/BL_ATLAS_HighMassDiphotons_ICHEP2016.pdf

[6] http://indico.cern.ch/event/432527/contributions/1072431/attachments/1320985/1980991/chiara_ichep.pdf

Comment: I am surprised, as I know the graviton should be massless and in many aspects similar to the photon (f.e. $E=h\nu$).

Comment: @peterh yes, but the proposed K-K theory give rises to a possible nonzero mass, as in ref [4]

Comment: [A mirage in the desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_(particle_physics))

Comment: @peterh  These are not 4D massless gravitons.. rather Kaluza-Klein type of gravitons, which are massive. For the diphoton, spin-0 or spin-2 are both possible... though we dont expect much from ICHEP now... the excess seem to have gone. Pity.

Comment: @xi45 The excess was there. But... something made it disappear. This is quite sad. Maybe it still exists in a different eigenfunction of our universes Hamiltonian.

Comment: @xi45 This is quite sad. :-( Some very new thing should be invented, I have a little bit of fear that the governments won't pay the next accelerator tunnel below the Equator. Couldn't be the particles accelerated by focused laser beams instead radio waves?

Comment: today at Chicago in the irchep meeting, news sound bad

Comment: @igael yeah I know. Truly disappointing.

Comment: @igael but I was told ATLAS results on spin-2 is getting more and more convincible (and the result is not released)... I hope there would be something.

Comment: @RoderickLee : I have an alert on irchep too but I miss this annouce, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The abstract for [your third reference](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09401) has a Particle Data Group block which gives $J=0$, but without much confidence.  A footnote on page 5 of that reference expresses skepticism that it's a graviton.

I'm afraid you're not going to get much more "updated" information than a preprint from six weeks ago.  The experiment is still going on.

[image]